# vb.net proccess communication using memory mapped files

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

*Hi. I converted this c# code :*

I m using this projet: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Inter-process-communication-e96e94e7

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        communicator = new MemoryMappedFileCommunicator("MemoryMappedShare", 4096);

        // This process reads data that begins in the position 0 and writes starting from the position 2000.
        communicator.ReadPosition = 0;
        communicator.WritePosition = 2000;

        // Creates an handler for the event that is raised when data are available in the
        // MemoryMappedFile.
        communicator.DataReceived += new EventHandler<MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs>(communicator_DataReceived);
        communicator.StartReader();
    }

    private void communicator_DataReceived(object sender, MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var receivedMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data);
        lstMessages.Items.Add(receivedMessage);
        lstMessages.SelectedIndex = lstMessages.Items.Count - 1;

        // Sends a message as a response.
        communicator.Write("Message from Windows App: data received at " + DateTime.Now);            
    }
```

to vb.net like this:

```
 Dim communicator As New MemoryMappedFileCommunicator("MemoryMappedShare", 4096)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' This process reads data that begins in the position 2000 and writes starting from the position 0. 
    communicator.ReadPosition = 2000
    communicator.WritePosition = 0

    ' Creates an handler for the event that is raised when data are available in the MemoryMappedFile. 

    AddHandler communicator.DataReceived, AddressOf New EventHandler(Of MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs)(communicator_DataReceived)
    communicator.StartReader() 

End Sub 

Private Sub communicator_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim receivedMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data)
    lstMessages.Items.Add(receivedMessage)
    lstMessages.SelectedIndex = lstMessages.Items.Count - 1

    ' Sends a message as a response.
    communicator.Write("Message from Windows App: data received at " + DateTime.Now)
End Sub
```

---

After conversion, i get error in vb.net code like this:
[VB.NET ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVoOF.png)

```
EDelegate 'System.EventHandler(Of MemoryMappedFileManager.MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs)' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.
```

At this line:

```
    AddHandler communicator.DataReceived, AddressOf New EventHandler(Of MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs)(communicator_DataReceived)
```

Comment: What error?  You just showed a picture of the error underlined... *what is the error message*?

Comment: I see your recent update, yet you still haven't provided the error message.  Please **post the error message**.

Comment: Delegate 'System.EventHandler(Of MemoryMappedFileManager.MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs)' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use both `AddressOf` and `New EventHandler` because `AddressOf` creates a delegate as well.

The recommended solution is to change it to:

```
AddHandler communicator.DataReceived, AddressOf communicator_DataReceived
```

The following works just as fine, but is however less readable:

```
AddHandler communicator.DataReceived, New EventHandler(Of MemoryMappedDataReceivedEventArgs)(AddressOf communicator_DataReceived)
```

Comment: A continue try above methods you give me but when i execute the code: it not receive incomming message.

Comment: @ElikarKananeMugangane : That's a different problem which I'm afriad I cannot help you with. You'd have to debug it on your own or ask another question about that.

Comment: @ElikarKananeMugangane : The above code adds the event handler unless no errors are thrown on any preceding lines, so your issue reside elsewhere. Are you sure the original code works, and are you sure you write to the correct place? -- Make sure everything else has been converted correctly and is working.